# ContextMenu en un botón dentro de un listview "no existe"

Tags: vb.net, wpf

Tengo un listview personalizado con un datatemplate. Entre los campos hay un botón con un ContextMenu que no logro que reconozca desde el código.

Pongo ejemplo del listview resumido, el original es mas grande, con varios campos y botones:

```
<ListView
x:Name="listUsuarios"
DataContext="{Binding Usuarios}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    
        <Border
            Margin="6,0,0,0"
            Padding="10,10,10,10"
            BorderBrush="Gray"
            BorderThickness="2"
            CornerRadius="5">
            
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ui:Button
                    Margin="0,0,6,0"
                    Click="ContexMenuItems_Click"
                    Icon="Copy24">
                    <ui:Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu x:Name="cmUsuarios" Opened="MenuUsuariosOpened">
                            <MenuItem
                                Name="CopyNameUserItem"
                                Click="CopyNameUser"
                                Header="Copiar Nombre" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </ui:Button.ContextMenu>
                </ui:Button>

                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="6,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="14"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="{Binding Path=Nombre, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Border
                        Margin="10,0,0,0"
                        Padding="8,3,8,3"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Background="#FF606060"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                        <TextBlock
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="12"
                            FontWeight="Bold"
                            Text="{Binding Path=Usuario, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

El codigo de cada item del ContextMenu funciona, encuentra el item seleccionado y copia el nombre al portapapeles. Ejemplo del código:

```
Private Sub CopyNameUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim menuitem As MenuItem = TryCast(sender, MenuItem)
        Dim item = TryCast(menuitem.DataContext, ListaUsuarios)
        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetText(item.Nombre)

End sub
```

Quiero hacer que pulsando el botón aparezca el ContextMenu, mediante .isOpen= true, que no haga falta pulsar el botón derecho. El problema es que no reconoce "cmUsuarios" en el código.

Ejemplo:

```
    Private Sub ContexMenuItems_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    
    cmUsuarios.IsOpen = True

    End Sub
```

"cmUsuarios" aprece subrayado y el error es que no está declarado.

¿alguien puede ayudarme a comprender por qué no lo encuentra?

Comment: El problema es que `cmUsuarios` no es ningun control determinado, es solo una plantilla para los items del `Listview`. Lo que supongo que podrías hacer es recorrer los items del `ListView` y obtener cada uno de los botones para suscribirte a su evento click, y ahi de nuevo obtener los controles del boton para abrir el context menu, algo similar a lo que explica en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321736/579895). Pero estas cosas son muchisimo mas sencillas si usas el patron MVVM, creando un command en lugar de suscribirte a click

Comment: He estado mirando ele ejmplo pero creo que no me vale. Yo manejo las propiedades directamente, no necesito recorrer la lista. Lo que necesito es que en codebehind me reconozca el contextmenu para poder manejarlo. Si ese mismo context menu se lo meto al listview si me deja manejarlo, cuando desaparece es cuando se lo aplico al boton dentro del item. Y no comprendo por que no llega a el. Es decir, puedo manejar el boton, sus estados, todo, pero no su contextmenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, la dejo por aqui por si a alguien le ayuda.

El objetivo era tener un boton que al pulsarlo salga un contextmenu con varios menuitems que se fueran mostrando u ocultando en funcion de la informacion del item. Es decir, por ejemplo un menuitem de copiar nombre, otro de copiar apellidos, telefono, email, etc, que no aparecieran si el item de listview no tiene nombre o apellidos, etc entre su informacion. Esto lo hacia desde el evento MenuOpened, casteaba la lista y si faltaba alguna informacion ocultaba los menuitems correspondientes. Eso cuando el contextmenu estaba en el listview, pero al moverlo al boton dentro del item, ya no lo encontraba.

Finalmente he comprendido con la ayuda de @Pikoh que no llego porque es una plantilla que no se crea hasta que el programa se ejecuta y se rellenan los items del listview, por lo que en el momento de programar no es accesible.

En este caso, lo que he hecho ha sido castear al sender para obtener el contextmenu en tiempo de ejecucion, y luego castear los items para, esta vez si, poder mostrarlos u ocultarlos.

El codigo seria algo así, resumido a un solo item y con la explicacion de que hace cada linea para mejor comprension:

```
Private Sub MenuUsuariosOpened(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As RoutedEventArgs)

'Encuentro el contextmenu del boton del item de la lista
Dim contextmenu As ContextMenu = TryCast(sender, ContextMenu)
'Aqui ya tengo el contextmenu, con un dim s as string = contextmenu.name obtendriamos que s = "cmUsuarios"

'Encuentro el item que necesito, en este caso el mnuitem 0 del contextmenu
Dim menuNombre As MenuItem = TryCast(contextmenu.Items(0), MenuItem)
'Habria que hacer lo mismo con el resto de items (contextmenu.Items(1)), etc

'Casteo los datos del item al que pertenece el boton con el contextmenu
Dim item = TryCast(contextmenu.DataContext, ListaUsuarios)

'Si no hay nombre, se oculta el menu de copiar nombre al portapaeles
If item.Nombre = "" Then menuNombre.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed

End Sub
```

Con esto ya se puede manejar cualquier menuitem del contextmenu pulsando boton derecho en el boton.

Si lo que queremos es que salga el contextmenu con el boton izquierdo, hay que eliminar el evento del context menu `Opened="MenuUsuariosOpened"` y manejarlo desde el evento click del boton, esta vez casteando el boton y obteniendo su contextmenu, asi:

```
'Encuentro el contextmenu del boton del item de la lista, obteniendo primero el boton pulsado
Dim button As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
Dim contextmenu As ContextMenu = button.ContextMenu
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien.